# function nil.team_name/0 is undefined

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have two kind of query. Both use same view.
One returns latest game JSON.
The other returns all games.

View

```
  def render("game.json", %{game: game}) do
    %{id: game.id,
      season_id: game.season_id,
      game_name: game.game_name,
      home_team_id: game.home_team_id,
      home_team_name: game.home_team.team_name,
      away_team_id: game.away_team_id,
      away_team_name: game.away_team.team_name,
      comments: game.comments}
  end
```

It works. And returns JSON.

```
  def latest_game do
    query = from g in Game,
            order_by: [desc: g.game_date, desc: g.game_time],
            preload: [:away_team, :home_team]
    query
      |> first(:game_date)
      |> first(:game_time)
      |> Repo.one()
  end
```

But it does not work.
It shows error `UndefinedFunctionError at GET /api/games function nil.team_name/0 is undefined` in view.

```
  def list_games do
    query = from g in Game,
            preload: [:away_team, :home_team]
    Repo.all(query)
  end
```

This is model.

```
defmodule Sample.Scoresheet.Game do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "games" do
    field :game_name, :string
    field :game_date, :date
    field :game_time, :time

    belongs_to :home_team, Sample.Scoresheet.Team
    belongs_to :away_team, Sample.Scoresheet.Team

    timestamps()
  end
```

Please give me some advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error

> `UndefinedFunctionError` at `GET /api/games` function `nil.team_name/0` is undefined

means that one (or both) of the associations

```
belongs_to :home_team, Sample.Scoresheet.Team
belongs_to :away_team, Sample.Scoresheet.Team
```

is not set, and either `game.home_team.team_name` or `game.away_team.team_name` fails to get to `team_name` because it returns `nil` as a team.

One should have constraints on the database (table `games`) making both foreign keys to `teams` mandatory, that way you’ll get meaningful error messages *and* the data will be always consistent.

Meanwhile, I’d suggest you to check your seeds and/or how you insert `games` into the database and make both `teams` a mandatory with [`Ecto.Changeset.validate_required/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_required/3).

Comment: Do you mean some team_id does not have team_name matchedin database?

Comment: Yes I found id which does not match any team.